# ALE and PSEN example waveforms - are highs and lows "flat enough"?

Tags: signal, microprocessor, waveform

Sorry if this is a silly question. All of my waveforms (square, rectangle, pulse) exhibit the kind of behavior in the image where the highs and lows are not super-flat.

Clock is 18MHz and these signals are approximately 1.5Mhz. This is an IDE-host interface to allow "modern" IDE drive to emulate a legacy one. Ground on these traces is with the probe's ground on the PCB ground (which is negative). This is a 5V TTL system.

1) Is this poor measurement or poor signal or both?

2) What practical impact will this have on my circuits? (I.e. will they work?)

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the time scale and amplitude?  Answer to #2 depends on the nature of your circuits.  Please illuminate what those are.

Comment: Also where is ground on those traces? What waveform do you get if you connect the scope probe signal input to the circuit's ground? (_should_ be a flat line...) Exactly what device(s) do you intend to drive with these signals?

Comment: Updated with following: Clock is 18MHz and these signals are approximately 1.5Mhz. This is an IDE-host interface to allow "modern" IDE drive to emulate a legacy one. Ground on these traces is with the probe's ground on the PCB ground (which is negative). Will connect probe to ground and update separately.